# How to get C-x C-e to display the result in octal and hexadecimal by default?

Tags: emacs, elisp

When I hit <kbd>C-x C-e</kbd> on a numeric expression a second time, the mini-buffer displays the result in octal and hexadecimal.  This is documented [here](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Lisp-Eval.html)

Is there a way to get the result in hex and octal on the first <kbd>C-x C-e</kbd>?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get that behavior with this advice.  Note, I made it also work for `eval-print-last-sexp` (aka <kbd>C-j</kbd>).  Just remove that from the list if you don't want that behavior.

```
(defadvice eval-expression-print-format (around eepf-tweak-output activate)
  "tweak output when this-command is eval-last-sexp or eval-print-last-sexp"
  (let ((last-command (if (memq this-command '(eval-last-sexp eval-print-last-sexp))
                          this-command
                        last-command)))
    ad-do-it))
```