# How to get C-x C-e to display only decimal and hexadecimal?

Tags: emacs, lisp, elisp, hex

This is a follow-up to [How to get C-x C-e to display the result in octal and hexadecimal by default?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3112893/how-to-get-c-x-c-e-to-display-the-result-in-octal-and-hexadecimal-by-default)

Is there a way to get <kbd>C-x C-e</kbd> to to display the result in decimal and hexadecimal only?

e.g.

```
(+ 40 2)
```

should produce

```
42 (#x2a)
```

instead of

```
42 (#o52, #x2a, ?*)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to rewrite/tweak the routine that creates the printed format for this.  Add the following to your .emacs and you'll be good to go.

```
(require 'simple)
(defun eval-expression-print-format (value)
  "Format VALUE as a result of evaluated expression.
Return a formatted string which is displayed in the echo area
in addition to the value printed by prin1 in functions which
display the result of expression evaluation."
  (if (and (integerp value)
           (or (not (memq this-command '(eval-last-sexp eval-print-last-sexp)))
               (eq this-command last-command)
               (if (boundp 'edebug-active) edebug-active)))
      (let ((char-string
             (if (or (if (boundp 'edebug-active) edebug-active)
                     (memq this-command '(eval-last-sexp eval-print-last-sexp)))
                 (prin1-char value))))
        (format " (#x%x)" value value))))
```

Comment: Thanks!  Is it standard practice to write replacements for functions that make up the emacs distribution?

Comment: @sigjuice standard? no.  Most of the customizations people want are satisfied by variable/hook changes, or worst-case using some advice.  That said, sometimes the only way to get what you want is to modify/overwrite the original code, which is a part of the design of Emacs (and the GPL).